# Can't save GBQ results in any format

Tags: google-bigquery, save, export-to-csv

I ran a query in Google BigQuery that is a basic Select * From [table] where [single column = (name)]

The results came out to about 310 lines and 48 columns, but when I try to save the results in ANY format, nothing happens.

I've tried saving as a view AND a table, which I can do just fine, but trying to download the results, or trying to export the results to GCP, fails every time. There is no error, no notification that something went wrong, literally nothing happens.

I'm about ready to yank out my hair and throw my computer out the window. I ran a query that was almost identical except for the (name) this morning and had no issue. Now it's after 4pm and it's not working.

All of my browsers are up to date, my logins are fine, my queries aren't reliant on tables that update during that time, I've restarted my computer four times in the hope that SOMETHING will help.

Has anyone had this issue? What else can I do to troubleshoot?

Comment: Is this specific to a table? What happens if you write `SELECT 1 x`. Can you save results then? It would be interesting to know more about your context - query, table schema, repeated records?

Comment: It is not table-specific. I just got into the office and attempted to save the same query results I was having an issue with yesterday, in the same way, and a small window in the bottom left popped up to say "Fetching results to save as CSV," which it didn't say yesterday.

Comment: I managed to save two different sets of query results and now I'm back to getting nada.

The query is :

SELECT * FROM `[Table Name Redacted]` where User = "[Name Redacted]"

Comment: Can you try with a different browser? Wondering if there's a browser extension or antivirus blocking normal behavior

Comment: I thought the same, so I tried with Firefox, Chrome, IE, and Safari with no luck.

Comment: Is this the old UI or new UI? Can you switch to the other one and try? Can you share any screenshot?

Comment: I didn't know there was a new UI - I'm using it as part of an organizational setup, so even if I'm on the old UI, I won't be able to update.

Is it okay to move to chat?

Comment: To make this more scalable - please enter details here that other people can use to help you. Otherwise use the BigQuery issue tracker so support can help you - and they will want more details too. https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/559654

Comment: What additional details would be helpful? (apologies, this is my first question on here and I'm not sure what information would make an impact)

Comment: A query, a URL, a screenshot, a table schema, a job id. Anything concrete people can use to reproduce.

Comment: Okay! What is the best way to give those specifics without also risking company information/proprietary information?

A screenshot would not be helpful because it would be of nothing happening, and I would have to redact so much from a data security perspective, there would be very little of the screen visible

Comment: Can you repeat the experiment with your GMail account? A screenshot or an URL would help us to know which UI you are actually using.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have any field of `RECORD (REPEATED)` type in your results? I had a similar problem today, trying to save my results to Google Sheets - literally nothing happened, no error message whatsoever - but fortunately (and quite puzzlingly) - I got this error while trying to save them to CSV on Google Drive instead: **"Operation cannot be performed on a nested schema. Field: ..."**. After removing the "offending" field, which was of `RECORD (REPEATED)` type, I was able to save to Google Sheets again.

Comment: There are no RECORD (REPEATED) fields in the results - I thought the same thing, but each line is unique data except for a column with the person's name